# Find all pairs $(a,b)$ of positive integers, such that $(a+1)(b+1)$ is divisible by $ab$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

*Problem:* Find all pairs $(a,b)$ of positive integers, such that $ab\mid (a+1)(b+1)$.
The solution from the source begins like this:
We have $(a+1)(b+1)=ab+a+b+1$, thus $a\mid b+1$ and $b\mid a+1$.(Why?)

Comment: What did you try ? What are your thoughts?

Comment: Does that "(Why?)" come from you or from the source?

Comment: No, that is the part where I can't understand.

Comment: @ArshiaMoniri: "No"?? Do you mean that the "(Why?)" comes _neither_ from you _nor_ from the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to have $ab\mid (a+1)(b+1)$. That implies $a\mid (a+1)(b+1)$. Inserting $(a+1)(b+1)=ab+a+b+1$, we get that $a\mid (ab+a+b+1)$. However, we already know that $a\mid ab+a$, so that means that $a\mid b+1$ as well. Similarly for $b$.

Now that we've proven the hint, we get that $a\leq b+1$ and $b\leq a+1$. Say that $a\leq b$. Then we have either $a=b$ or $a+1=b$. In the first case we get $a\mid a+1$, so $\boxed{a=b=1}$ is a solution (as soon as you've checked it). In the second case we get $a\mid a+2$, so either $a=1$ or $a=2$. That means that you need to check $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$ and see whether they are solutions, and then you're done.